# how create another field in a struct in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a struct with information.
I want to put more field and put in the new fields information from other tables.
How i put new fields in a struct that have information? At matlab!

Thanks

Comment: You just do it. For example if you have a struct `S` with field `F1` and now you want to add a field `F2` just do `S.F2 = 'blablabla....'`

Comment: But if i want later put the information? And that the field will be empty untill i will put there?

Comment: `S.F2 = []` or from the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) `s = struct(field1,value1,...,fieldN,valueN)`